# Finding median in MATLAB taking a lot of time

Tags: matlab, optimization, median

I have a row vector `X` for which I want to find the median.
I am using MATLAB's function `median()` to find the same but it is proving to be the bottleneck in my code.

Is there a faster implementation available for finding median in any other language?

Comment: Usually it is hard to beat the performance of the builtin function. `median` is an m-file, so you can see its code. From a quick look, it seems to do some checks and then: sort the elements and take the middle element, or the average of the two middle elements. You could do the latter manually skipping the checks, but it will probably take almost the same time

Comment: 1. How long is X? 2. Is X a vector of reals, matrices, cells? what do you put in X? 3. What MATLAB version are you using? 4. How much RAM is installed in the platform you are using? 5. When you say 'bottleneck' do you mean it takes for instance 7 minutes but you see a result, even if only from time to time? or does it always crash MATLAB and the only way back is to kill MATLAB process and launch MATLAB again?

Comment: to Atharva: I assume that to simplify things you do X=X(:); before doing result=median(X); don't you?

Comment: @JohnBG Why would `X=X(:)` simplify things? If `X` is a vector, like OP claims, there is no difference. If it’s a matrix you get totally different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to improve the speed of calculation by several orders of magnitude but not by a different implementation.
Rather, I just converted the vector into a `gpuArray` and then fed into the `median()` function. For large vectors this reduced the time of calculation by several orders of magnitude. But slowed things down for shorter arrays, I believe this is because time was being used up in transferring the vector to memory in gpu.
I found the transition length of the vector to be ~450. That is for vectors shorter than 450 directly feeding the vector into the `median()` function is better and for longer ones converting to `gpuArray` and then feeding into the `median()` function is faster.